# How can I use \pause command in \documentclass{slides}?

Tags: pause

I am editing a beamer created by someone else using `\documentclass{slides}`. Unfortunately, it doesn't accept `\pause` command during slides. Changing from "slides" to "beamer" wouldn't work because of other formatting errors. (It's a huge presentation).

I would like to make the equivalent of the following code work (with the `\pause` uncommented, of course).

```
\documentclass{slides}

    \begin{document}
\begin{slide}
Test1
%\pause
Test2
\end{slide}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Personally, I avoid beamer since it redefines EVERYTHING.  Instead I use the texpower package.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`slides` is one class. `beamer` is another class. Each is designed to serve a quite specific purpose.

Not only can you not use `\pause` with `slides`, `slides` is not designed to create LCD presentation slides at all. It is designed to create transparencies of the kind that those of us who are old enough used with an ancient technology known as an overhead projector.

In particular, the page dimensions and width to height ratios supported are not suitable for LCD slides. `slides` produces slides designed to be *printed* - not *projected*.

For example, I printed slides onto US letter paper and then used a photocopier to create versions on transparencies for use in class.

So you don't use overlay specifications etc. Commands such as `\pause` make no sense.

`slides` has two possible equivalents of `\pause`.

1. The most popular, I suspect, is a sheet of paper which you use to render the lower part of the transparency opaque while you talk about the top.

   - As you move through the sheet, you shift the paper down, uncovering more of the transparency.
   - The light from below is blocked by the paper, so only the uncovered part of the slide is shown on the screen.
   - There is no LaTeX command for this as far as I know.
2. Apparently, `slides` does support an `\invisible` macro which renders the text invisible on the slide.

   - This allows you to create several slides such that subsequent slides can be overlaid on top of earlier ones.
   - If you want to leave a gap initially and then fill it in, for example, you could use `\invisible` for the stuff which will fill in the gap on the next slide.
   - So you'd have 2 very similar `slide` environments, the first using `\invisible{}` for stuff in the gap and the second rendering the same stuff visible.
   - However, this is likely to work properly only if you do not alter the default fonts used by the class.

Comment: Ah, the good old [Polylux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylux_%28overhead_projector%29).  :-)