# Document class: slides

Tags: beamer

I am using some time now the Beamer class for my presentations, courses, etc. Recently I found in a book for LateX (dated from 1999) that there is a standard document class called `slides` for presentations.

Searching in Internet I did not find any information. Is it considered obsolete compared to Beamer class?

Comment: The version at [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/slides?lang=en) dates of 2014, so its not *that* obsolete. I don't know about functionality, though. You can take a look at the documentation in the link above... **Edit:** Section 5 of the documentation says: `Warning: The implementation is still very experimental and may change internally very much.`

Comment: I am under the impression that `slides` is primarily meant to produce real slides, e.g. for overhead projectors

Comment: related answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/308427/36296

Comment: Thank you all for your useful comments. `slides` serves another purpose therefore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparing `beamer` and `slides` is like comparing apples to oranges - both classes have a different focus.

- `slides` is primarily meant to create slides for overhead projectors. You can see this for example from the default paper size of this class (A4 or letter).
- For `beamer` on the other hand, the default output is meant for video projectors